# Review button shown when “There are no review queues available to you”

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

Note - this is completely different to ["There are no review queues available to you" - Hey?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293479/there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you-hey)

---

I accessed Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta today while browsing the main site and clicking on one of the Hot Meta Posts.

My attention started to drift, and wandered over to the top-bar, and on to the review queue button.

I didn't know what reviewing privileges were available to me, so I clicked on it, and...

[image: Review queues - There are no review queues available to you]

That was pointless. I know I haven't been review banned, because I have never reviewed on PPCG Meta.

I don't have enough reputation on other sites to confirm this behaviour, and I don't know whether it's a result of Code Golf's different privilege system, which is why I haven't taken it to main Meta.

> Could the help centre or some other helpful item take the place of the review queue button?

One possible rationale - new users who don't know much about the review queue may think that the button is useless and ignore it even when it does do something.

Comment: Short answer: the new top bar is terrible in every way.

Comment: I think it'd be worse if they hid the button if there weren't reviews.  You couldn't memorize the position of the buttons because they would be in different spots based on whether there were reviews.

Comment: @NathanMerrill But why not the help centre, like other sites with low-rep?

Comment: From the answer, this appears to be by design. If this is a major/significant issue, I would honestly recommend bring it up on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as this should theoretically affect all sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen when you have enough reputation to access the *First Posts* and the *Late Answers* review queues, but not enough reputation to access any other queues.

On the main site, the review button shows you those two queues. On the meta site, the button still is there (presumably because it doesn't check for main and meta separately), but on meta there is no *First Posts* or *Late Answers* queue, so there are no queues you have the privilege to access.

And it does happen on other Stack Exchange sites as well, not just here on PPCG. That's how I found it out, actually.